# Should I remove the comma in the sentence?

Tags: punctuation, commas

I have a sentence in my writing:

```
I believe that my interest, abilities, combined with 
my IT experiences make me an ideal candidate for this programme.
```

The `Grammarly` application suggests to add a comma after experiences, I don't understand why, as there is no explanation in detail.

[image]

Can you help me to point out what the incorrect in my sentence?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The problem is not a lack of a comma. It's a lack of the word *and*.  My interest and abilities, combined with my IT experience (NOT plural) make me an ideal candidate.  Or even:  My interest, abilities, and IT experience make me an ideal candidate.

Comment: where should I add the `and`? could you please tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beginning of the sentence (up to "experiences"), is an *introductory phrase*, and therefore warrants a comma. (Rule 4a from Grammarbook - https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp).

So: "I believe that my interest, abilities, combined with my IT experience, make me an ideal candidate for this programme." (note "experience" instead of "experiences").

For what it's worth, I find that the way the sentence uses "combined" to be awkward because my mind is trying to create a relation but struggles between at least two possibilities:

- is the relation with "interest and abilities"?
- or is the relation with just "abilities"?

I don't think it is necessary, but you could consider tweaking slightly to 
either:

- I believe that my interest and abilities, combined with my IT experiences, make me an ideal candidate for this programme.
- I believe that my interest, abilities, and IT experience, make me an ideal candidate for this programme.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I believe that "I believe that my interests and abilities, combined with my IT experiences, make me an ideal candidate for this programme" is the correct one. Both the character's interest and ability are assets here, and "and" throws each one into sharper relief, while the well-meaning but much-abused comma glosses over them.

Comment: very clear. Thanks a lot for your help.